# load data from REST API to EXT JS form's selectfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, sencha-touch

I have been continuing learning Ext JS framework.

Now I have to do next thing: load some data from server to particular form's selectfields through a REST API.

This is my proxy store:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.store.RESTstore',{ 
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeID:'reststore',
proxy: {
    type:'rest',
    url:'http://localhost:8001/api/fieldvalues/'
},
autoLoad: true});
```

How should I links REST api with form's field? I have found few examples with model, but how it can be realised witout using of model? If I want use exist forms?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fields in model.

example:

```
model:
    fields:[
    {type: 'string',name: 'CODE'}
    ]
```

---

```
view:
{
xtype:'textfield',
reference:'CODE',
name:'CODE'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!  Yes, it's obvious. But can I add to model already created forms with some selectfields?